# Best solution to integrate independent applications into a Django (& React) platform?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-sites, django-tenants, django-hosts

I have a general platform that I want to evolve.

The platform is hosted on a domain like "https://www.example.com".

For certain specific users, I would like to give them access to a completely independent application (several applications, independent platform) from their profile on a subdomain like "https://subdomain.example.com".

**I would like these applications to have**:

- Their own database
- Be accessible only for authenticated and authorized users
- Their own server

The Django project of the general platform is written in Django/React.

Before launching this project, I am wondering about the best way to integrate these independent applications into the main platform.

I have done some research and manipulation, but I don't know how to decide on the project architecture: **django-host, django-tenant, django-site** ...

**Below is my current architecture**

[image: architecture django]

What is the best possible option to connect other independent applications to the general platform with the current users?